# Date.now() not shown in placeholder date type in form - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have my date coming from server in the form of Date.now() and stored in order.date

```
<input type="date" data-ng-model="order.date" id="date" 
    name="date" min="2013-01-01" max="2020-12-31" required/>
```

Currently order.date is sent by server and stores in the form Date.now(). Even when order.date is valid, it shows dd/mm/yy as placeholder.

It works well when order.date is set with

```
order.date = new Date(2013, 9, 22)
```

but not

```
order.date = Date.now();
```

It can also be tested in http://plnkr.co/edit/sl9OlHSNRPo2LXzupOxT?p=preview.

[image]

Comment: you want to show current date as placeholder,right?

Comment: Not the current date but the date present in order.date

Comment: your plnkr doesn't containt the exact code,which you have written here. update it if possible.

Comment: Date.now() might be returning different format date. so first you have to convert that returned date to required date format and than assigned it to order.date variable scope.

Answer (score 2):

Seems problem with `date` input type, here is the thing i have done to make it work

```
angular.module('dateInputExample', [])
 .controller('DateController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
   // change the format to "yyyy-MM-dd"
   $scope.value = $filter('date')(Date.now(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
 }]);
```

and in template add `value` attribute

```
<input 
   type="date" 
   value="{{value}}" 
   id="exampleInput" 
   name="input" 
   ng-model="value"
   placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" 
   min="2012-01-01" 
   max="2030-12-31" 
   required />
```

here is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ajaVIAW0mk2Ru4ucuynI?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Date.now() might be returning different format date. so first you have to convert that returned date to required date format and than assigned it to order.date variable scope

```
var todayDate = Date.now();

$scope.order={};

$scope.order.date=$filter('date')(todayDate, "yyyy/MM/dd"); 
// don't forget to inject $filter in your controller
//then it will work as you want
```

Answer (score 0):

try to bind the order.date on the body of the page and see if it is being set, e.g `<p>{{order.date}}</p>` and also check if you're using the right controller for that view or if the controller has been defined.

Comment: No its problem with format of the date rather than it being inaccessible